# Why type required when defining default parameter values?

Tags: scala, type-inference

When defining a class with default parameter values why it is required to provide the type of default parameters explicitly ?

For example:

```
scala> case class Person(name:String = "SomeOne")  
defined class Person
```

But following error is encountered when the type is not provided explicitly:

```
scala> case class Person(name = "SomeOne")  
<console>:1: error: ':' expected but '=' found.
   case class Person(name = "SomeOne")
```

Is there any reason why the type inference system cannot identify the type of the default parameter values ?

Answer (score 3):

In Scala all following declarations are valid

```
case class AnyPerson(name: Any = "SomeOne")
case class StringPerson(name: String = "SomeOne")
case class CharSequencePerson(name: CharSequence = "SomeOne")
```

And even this one is valid

```
implicit def stringToLenght(name: String) = name.length()

case class Person(name:Int = "SomeOne")
```

In this case name default value is 7.

So number of possible options is a sum of:

1. All inheritance of the type
2. All implicit conversions in the scope for the Type

Let's say by mistake in your code you are doing something like this:

```
val person = AnyPerson()
val anotherPerson = AnyPerson(name = person.name + 9)
```

In this case. Have you made an error, or you gave compiler a hint, of what real meaning of the name is?

Language can have a rule for compiler to make assumption of what developer meant. But it would make code harder to read, understand, and this would be highly error prone for the final users.